# SpeechKit transcribing audio file

Tags: ios, avcapturedevice

Is it possible to use Nuance's SpeechKit for iOS to use an audio or video file as it's source, vs. automatically using the microphone?

I created a project here:

https://github.com/jeffreality/iOSVideoTranscriber

using SpeechKit, but it transcribes off of the microphone (thus disabling video capture).  If I could have it transcribe after the fact, that would work as a work-around.

Comment: This would also be useful if, at the time the video is recorded, there is no internet available (Nuance sends the audio to their servers to transcribe)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can use [Nuance's Http services](http://dragonmobile.nuancemobiledeveloper.com/public/Help/HttpInterface/HTTP_web_services_for_NCS_clients_1.0_programmer_s_guide.pdf).

You'll get to handle the recording and send the http request.